# Drupal jquery SyntaxError: missing } after function body

Tags: jquery, drupal

It's simple drupal jquery code as below:
but it is not correctly,report a bug as

SyntaxError: missing } after function body var l.

is there anyone has simulate bug? How do i fix it?

```
  (function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
 "use strict";
 Drupal.behaviors.paypro_out_statistic = {
    attach: function (context) {

      $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-end").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
      $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-end").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-fast-forward");


    }
  }
 })(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is actual drupal jquery code:
before is product environment code, it works, but i don't know what i do , and it report a bug as above, the same code, different environment. my dev env report this.

```
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
"use strict";
Drupal.behaviors.paypro_out_statistic = {
attach: function (context) {
  //公共调用方法
  function Merger(gridName, CellName) {
      //得到显示到界面的id集合
      var mya = $("#" + gridName + "").getDataIDs();
      //当前显示多少条
      var length = mya.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          //从上到下获取一条信息
          var before = $("#" + gridName + "").jqGrid('getRowData', mya[i]);
          //定义合并行数
          var rowSpanTaxCount = 1;
          for (var j = i + 1; j <= length; j++) {
              //和上边的信息对比 如果值一样就合并行数+1 然后设置rowspan 让当前单元格隐藏
              var end = $("#" + gridName + "").jqGrid('getRowData', mya[j]);

              if (before[CellName] == end[CellName]) {
                  rowSpanTaxCount++;
                  $("#" + gridName).setCell(mya[j], CellName, "", { display: "none" });

              } else {
                  rowSpanTaxCount = 1;
                  break;
              }
              $("#" + CellName + "" + mya[i] + "").attr("rowspan", rowSpanTaxCount);
          }
      }
  }
  $("#statis").jqGrid({
    url: Drupal.url('ajax/cg_statis/paypro/out/statistic/collection'),
    datatype: "json",
          height : 'auto',
    colNames: ['ID', '收款方', '收款银行', '收款账号', '币种', '金额', '已付', '未付', '开始时间', '截止时间'],
    colModel:[
      {name: 'id', index: 'id', sorttype: "int", width: 30, editable: false},
      {name: 'name', index: 'name', editable: false},
      {name: 'bank', index: 'bank', editable: false},
      {name: 'account', index: 'account', editable: false},
      {name: 'ftype', index: 'ftype', editable: false},
      {name: 'amount', index: 'amount', editable: false},
      {name: 'has', index: 'has', editable: false},
      {name: 'not', index: 'not', editable: false},
      {name: 'begin', index: 'begin', editable: false},
      {name: 'end', index: 'end', editable: false},
    ],
            rowNum : 10,
            rowList : [10, 50, 100, 10000],
            pager : '#statisnav',
            sortname : 'id',
            toolbarfilter : true,
            viewrecords : true,
            sortorder : "desc",
            autowidth : true,
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
    },
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
    caption: '供应商收款统计',
 });


  $("#statis").jqGrid(
    'navGrid',
    '#statisnav',
    {edit:false,add:false,del:false},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {multipleSearch:true, multipleGroup:true}
  );

  $("#outstatis").jqGrid({
    url: Drupal.url('ajax/cg_statis/paypro/out/fk/statistic/collection'),
    datatype: "json",
          height : 'auto',
    colNames: ['ID', '公司名', '银行', '账号', '币种', '金额', '已付', '未付', '开始时间', '截止时间'],
    colModel:[
      {name: 'id', index: 'id', sorttype: "int", width: 30, editable: false},
      {name: 'name', index: 'name', editable: false},
      {name: 'bank', index: 'bank', editable: false},
      {name: 'account', index: 'account', editable: false},
      {name: 'ftype', index: 'ftype', editable: false},
      {name: 'amount', index: 'amount', editable: false},
      {name: 'has', index: 'has', editable: false},
      {name: 'not', index: 'not', editable: false},
      {name: 'begin', index: 'begin', editable: false},
      {name: 'end', index: 'end', editable: false},
    ],
            rowNum : 10,
            rowList : [10, 50, 100, 10000],
            pager : '#outstatisnav',
            sortname : 'id',
            toolbarfilter : true,
            viewrecords : true,
            sortorder : "desc",
            autowidth : true,
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
    },
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
    caption: '我司付款统计',
 });


  $("#outstatis").jqGrid(
    'navGrid',
    '#outstatisnav',
    {edit:false,add:false,del:false},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {multipleSearch:true, multipleGroup:true}
  );


  $("#parts").jqGrid({
    url: Drupal.url('ajax/cg_statis/part/closer'),
    datatype: "json",
          height : 'auto',
    colNames: ['ID', '名称', '类型', '需求数量', '需求单号', '需求日期', '采购单号', '预计交付日期', '付款单号', '支付单号', '物流单', '创建人', '创建时间'],
    colModel:[
      {name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 20, editable: false},
      {name: 'name', index: 'name', editable: false},
      {name: 'parttype', index: 'parttype', editable: false},
      {name: 'num', index: 'num', width: 40, editable: false},
      {name: 'rno', index: 'rno', width: 40, editable: false},
      {name: 'requiredate', index: 'requiredate', width: 60,  editable: false},
      {name: 'cno', index: 'cno', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'plandate', index: 'plandate',  width: 60, editable: false},
      {name: 'fno', index: 'fno', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'pno', index: 'pno', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'ship_supply_no', index: 'ship_supply_no', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'uid', index: 'uid', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'created', index: 'created', width: 40,  editable: false},
    ],
            rowNum : 10,
            rowList : [10, 100, 500],
            pager : '#partsnav',
            sortname : 'id',
            autowidth : true,
    toolbarfilter : true,
    viewrecords: true,
    recordpos: 'right',
    caption: "需求配件明细表",
 });

  $("#parts").jqGrid('navGrid', "#partsnav", {
    edit : false,
    add : false,
    del : false,
    search: true,
    refresh:true,
  },{
    reloadAfterSubmit: false // del options
  });

  $("#zijin").jqGrid({
    url: Drupal.url('ajax/cg_statis/paypro/zijin/total/collection'),
    datatype: "json",
          height : 'auto',
    colNames: ['ID', '申请人', '申请部门', '物品名称', '物品类别', '供应商', '数量', '单价', '币种', '本次付款金额', '是否为预算', '应付金额', '已付金额', '所属公司', '存放地点', '原因/备注', '预计付款公司', '实际付款时间', '实际与计划差异', '备注', '创建时间'],
    colModel:[
      {name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 20, editable: false},
      {name: 'uid', index: 'uid', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'depart', index: 'depart', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 40,  editable: false,
          //①给当前想合并的单元格设置id
          cellattr: function(rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
              return 'id=\'name' + rowId + "\'";
          }
      },
      {name: 'parttype', index: 'parttype', width: 40,  editable: false,
          //①给当前想合并的单元格设置id
          cellattr: function(rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
              return 'id=\'parttype' + rowId + "\'";
          }
      },
      {name: 'supply_id', index: 'supply_id', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'num', index: 'num', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'unitprice', index: 'unitprice', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'ftype', index: 'ftype', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'thispaypre', index: 'thispaypre', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'ispre', index: 'ispre', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'haspay', index: 'haspay', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'tocompany', index: 'tocompany', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'located', index: 'located', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'thewhy', index: 'thewhy', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'planpayforcompany', index: 'planpayforcompany', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'paydate', index: 'paydate', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'diffamount', index: 'diffamount', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'description', index: 'description', width: 40,  editable: false},
      {name: 'created', index: 'created', width: 40,  editable: false},
    ],
            rowNum : 500,
            rowList : [500, 1000, 5000],
            pager : '#zijinnav',
            sortname : 'id',
    gridview: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: '100%',
    caption: "资金总结表",
    gridComplete: function() {
        //②在gridComplete调用合并方法
        var gridName = "zijin";
        //Merger(gridName, 'name');
        //Merger(gridName, 'parttype');
    }
 });

  $("#zijin").jqGrid('navGrid', "#zijinnav", {
    edit : false,
    add : false,
    del : false,
    search: false,
    refresh:true,
  },{
    reloadAfterSubmit: false // del options
  });
        $(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function() {
            $("#statis").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $("#content").width());
            $("#outstatis").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $("#content").width());
            $("#parts").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $("#content").width());
            $("#zijin").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $("#content").width());
        })



  // remove classes
  $(".ui-jqgrid").removeClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content");
  $(".ui-jqgrid-view").children().removeClass("ui-widget-header ui-state-default");
  $(".ui-jqgrid-labels, .ui-search-toolbar").children().removeClass("ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr");
  $(".ui-jqgrid-pager").removeClass("ui-state-default");
  $(".ui-jqgrid").removeClass("ui-widget-content");

  // add classes
  $(".ui-jqgrid-htable").addClass("table table-bordered table-hover");
  $(".ui-jqgrid-btable").addClass("table table-bordered table-striped");

  $(".ui-pg-div").removeClass().addClass("btn btn-sm btn-primary");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-plus").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-plus");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-pencil").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-pencil");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-trash").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-trash-o");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-search").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-search");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-refresh").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-refresh");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-disk").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-save").parent(".btn-primary").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-cancel").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-times").parent(".btn-primary").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");

  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-prev").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-prev").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-backward");

  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-first").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-first").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-fast-backward");

  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-next").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-next").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-forward");

  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-end").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
  $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-end").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-fast-forward");


}
}
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```